# Softlayer: Create flavor vm instance using Terraform

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I found there exist some flavor vm type, e.g. c1.1x1 or b1.2x4 in bluemix portal site.
But [ibm_compute_vm_instance](https://ibm-cloud.github.io/tf-ibm-docs/v0.6.0/r/compute_vm_instance.html) seems only be able to setup cores.

Could i be able to create for type c1 or m1? 
Or, which cpu type it is by default while deploying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM Terraform does not have an attribute to put a flavor’s value that is needed to create a VM, the same that you do in blumix portal, or the presetId attribute that is used in other languages.

This issue has already been reported, you can see it in this link: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/terraform-provider-ibm/issues/151

To create a new VM by terraform you have to choose the CPU, RAM and FIRST DISK separately.

e.g  you can choose this flavor:

```
"name" :" C1.2x2x25 " 
It means (2 x 2.0 GHz Cores, 2 GB RAM, 25 GB (SAN) First Disk)
```

There is no default CPU type while deploying. You have to choose one.

To find these values you can use the following rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]-[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions
```

You will find here the following result:

```
{
            "flavor": {
                "keyName": "C1_2X2X25",
                "name": "C1.2x2x25",
                "configuration": [
                    {
                        "category": {
                            "name": "Computing Instance"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "hourlyRecurringFee": ".045",
                            "item": {
                                "description": "2 x 2.0 GHz Cores"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "category": {
                            "name": "First Disk"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                            "item": {
                                "description": "25 GB (SAN)"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "category": {
                            "name": "RAM"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "hourlyRecurringFee": ".03",
                            "item": {
                                "description": "2 GB"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "totalMinimumHourlyFee": "0.075",
                "totalMinimumRecurringFee": "49.77"
            },
            "template": {
                "id": null,
                "supplementalCreateObjectOptions": {
                    "flavorKeyName": "C1_2X2X25"
                }
            }
        },
```

This is an example how could you send the terraform request:

```
resource "ibm_compute_vm_instance" "twc_terraform_sample" {
    hostname = "twc-terraform-sample-name"
    domain = "bar.example.com"
    os_reference_code = "DEBIAN_7_64"
    datacenter = "wdc01"
    network_speed = 10
    hourly_billing = true
    private_network_only = false
    cores = 2
    memory = 2048
    disks = [25]
    dedicated_acct_host_only = true
    local_disk = false
}
```

The RAM (memory) that you have to send must be in MB (e.g 2GB will be 2048 MB)

Comment: Thanks for reply, i still need to know for example, when i  send "cores = 1 memory=2048 disks=[100]" in terrafrom, does it means to be b1.1x25x100 or bl1.1x25x100 or maybe something else..? Because their price is not the same.

Comment: For your example it will be B1.1x2x100, it means ( 1 CPU, 2 GB RAM, 100 GB (SAN) FIRST DISK ), you have to send the memory ram data in MB is for that, 2GB will be 2048 MB.

Answer (score 2):

They has add the ability to create flaovr using [terraform ref](https://ibm-cloud.github.io/tf-ibm-docs/v0.8.0/r/compute_vm_instance.html).
Check the new field 'flavor_key_name'.

But it still need setup 'local_disk'. 'local_disk' is 'true' while using using bl1 or bl2, or it should be 'false'.